# Check if session key exists in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to check it a session key has already been set inside a controller. The documentation states that it is possible to check if an item exists in an array and that's it.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Can't you just do `if (Session::has('your_key'))` ?

Answer (score 25):

you can use

```
if($request->session()->has('key'))
{
}
```

Comment: Code is not enough. Please explain it.

Comment: in laravel 5 or its upper syntax has been changed that's why you will write code like this for check the session is exist or not. read the session documentation for laravel 5.2. it makes you concept clear.

Answer (score 16):

As pointed out by @DavidDomain in the question comments, probably the best way of doing it is to use

```
if(Session::has('...'))
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use `Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY')` in both blade and controller

controller ex:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class add_classController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    if (Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY')){
      // do some thing if the key is exist
    }else{
      //the key does not exist in the session
    }

  }
}
```

blade ex:

```
@if (Session::has('YOUR_SESSION_KEY'))
{{-- do something with session key --}}
@else
{{-- session key dosen't exist  --}}
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
if(Session::has('your_key')){
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($request->session()->exists('your_key'){
// 
}
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of why and how it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
@if (session()->has('hasCoupon'))
    [{{ Session::get('hasCoupon')['name'] }}]</span>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Or shorter, without using the Session Facade: `if(session()->exists('key_here'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ( session::has('message') 

{{ session::get('message') }}
@endif
```

or

```
@if (session->has->('message'))

{{session->

@endif
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since this exact answer has already been given and the question is 6 years old, duplicate answer do not contribute a lot. Perhaps you can take a look at newer questions without answers to provide your help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this new laravel syntax

```
 @if(session()->has('success'))
  //rest of code here
 @endif
```